# I'm getting gem errors when running middleman server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, middleman

When I run `middleman server` I get

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      activesupport (~> 4.2)
      padrino-helpers (~> 0.13.0)
      memoist (~> 0.14)
      uglifier (~> 3.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
```

I tried to do `gem clean` as well as `gem clean [gem-name]` but I still get those errors.

I've read that bundler and guarding gems can help but when I run bundle exec guard I get `error bundler: command not found: guard` and I did previously run `gem bundler install`

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

this means that you have more than one version of the listed gems installed on your system. Uninstall the older versions of the gem and try again.
you can try

```
gem uninstall [gem-name]
```